# Unable to specify return type for Django Manager for Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, mypy

I have implemented a custom user model inheriting from `AbstractUser`:

```py
"""This module contains models for the users app."""
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from users.managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractUser):
    """Class that implements a custom User model with admin permissions."""

    # Fields to remove from AbstractUser
    username = None  # type: ignore
    date_joined = None  # type: ignore

    # Fields to modify from AbstractUser
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    # Custom fields
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    second_last_name = models.CharField(_('second last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS: list[str] = []

    objects = UserManager()  # type: ignore

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.email
```

I have also defined my custom manager `UserManager` which inherits from `BaseUserManager` as follows:

```py
from typing import Any

from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email: str, password: str, **extra_fields: Any):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email for user must be set.')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email: str, password: str, **extra_fields: Any):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

However, if I add the return type, `User`, using type hint, I am getting an error:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email: str, password: str, **extra_fields) -> User:
```

This is the error I get when I run `mypy`:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 268, in get_model
Error constructing plugin instance of NewSemanalDjangoPlugin

    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'user'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 211, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 270, in get_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: App 'users' doesn't have a 'User' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mypy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_entry())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy/__main__.py", line 11, in console_entry
    main(None, sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
  File "mypy/main.py", line 87, in main
  File "mypy/main.py", line 165, in run_build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 179, in build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 229, in _build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 475, in load_plugins
  File "mypy/build.py", line 453, in load_plugins_from_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/main.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.django_context = DjangoContext(django_settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/django/context.py", line 88, in __init__
    apps, settings = initialize_django(self.django_settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/django/context.py", line 72, in initialize_django
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/src/users/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from users.managers import UserManager
  File "/src/users/managers.py", line 7, in <module>
    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
  File "/src/users/managers.py", line 16, in UserManager
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 164, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed
```

This is my settings file:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import environ

env = environ.Env()


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
BASE_DIR = PROJECT_DIR.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env.str('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', default=False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS: list[str] = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third-party apps
    'django_extensions',
    # local apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chacra.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chacra.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {'default': env.db()}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
# Media files
# MEDIA_ROOT: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-root
# MEDIA_URL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-url

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.joinpath('media')
MEDIA_URL = env.str('MEDIA_URL', default='/media/')
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.joinpath('static')
STATIC_URL = env.str('STATIC_URL', default='/static/')


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Jupyter Notebooks
# fmt: off
NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS = [
    '--ip', '0.0.0.0',
    '--allow-root',
    '--no-browser',
]
# fmt: on

# Model to use to represent a user
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Comment: Can you show your `settings.py` file?

Comment: @AyushGupta, I just shared it.

Comment: Can you also share `UsersConfig`

Comment: Have you added `users.apps.UsersConfig` in `__init__.py` file? How about adding `users` in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of `users.apps.UsersConfig`? Does that work?

Comment: @AYushGupta, I don't see the point of adding that. The app is loaded properly. I was able to run the migrations, but I cannot specify the typing.

Comment: No that's not the case. See whenever you are adding an *app configuration* in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you must put `default_config_app` in `__init__.py`

Comment: @AyushGupta, what `__init__.py` file do you mean? The one in this app `users` or the one in the project's package?

Answer (score 0):

**Could you please add the following code in your user model**

```py
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```

**Your `User` model should be like this**

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    """Class that implements a custom User model with admin permissions."""

    # Fields to remove from AbstractUser
    username = None  # type: ignore
    date_joined = None  # type: ignore

    # Fields to modify from AbstractUser
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    # Custom fields
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    second_last_name = models.CharField(_('second last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS: list[str] = []

    objects = UserManager()  # type: ignore

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = _('user')
       verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.email
```

Comment: this is not working. However, it doesn't make sense to add the `Meta` class since it is the same class as the one from which it is inheriting `AbstractUser`.

Answer (score 0):

While adding a *dotted path to a configuration class* in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you must put `default_app_config` in `__init__.py` file in that particular app.

In your case, put `default_app_config='users.apps.UsersConfig'` in the `__init__.py` file located in `users` app.

Comment: this is not working. In addition, it seems this way to specify the default app config was used before Django 3.2 according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors).

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Just add `users` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and tell me if it worked.

Comment: It didn't I changed from `'users.apps.UsersConfig'` to `'users'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and I added that `default_app_config`, and it does not work.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf No this time just add `users` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and remove `default_app_config`